# React-Native FlatList ListHeaderComponent ignores shouldComponentUpdate

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

In React-Native, using a `FlatList` with a `ListHeaderComponent` lets me to believe that the shouldComponenupdate function in the ListHeaderComponent (though executed) is ignored. My  component always rerenders even though I return *false* in shouldComponentUpdate. How would I stop the ListHeaderComponent from rerendering?

```
<Card>
     <FlatList data={comments}
              ListHeaderComponent={() => <PostHeader navigation={this.props.navigation} post={this.props.post} />}
              style={{flex:1}}
              onRefresh={() => this.props.getPost(mediaId, 'newsfeed', true)}
              refreshing={isRefreshing}
              keyExtractor={(comment) => comment.id}
              removeClippedSubviews={false}
              renderItem={(comment) => <Comment comment={comment.item} /> } />

    <PostComment newComment={newComment}
                 postComment={() => this.props.postComment(newComment.content, mediaId, profile.id)}
                 reset={()=> this.props.resetNewComment}
                 onTextChange={this.props.newCommentTextChanged} />
    {Platform.OS.toLocaleLowerCase() === 'ios' &&
    <KeyboardSpacer />
    }
  </Card>
```

Placing the  before the FlatList stops the undesired behavior, but this would require wrapping the lot in a ScrollView which I rather avoid when using a FlatList.

Comment: In which component are you returning false in `shouldComponentUpdate`?

Comment: Sorry,  will update Question. In the PostHeader component

Comment: Problem is that even thogh PostHeader component is not re-rendering the parent component does. This mean PostHeader is also re-rendered.

Comment: Why does shouldcomponentUpdate within the PostHeader successfully prevent the component from rerendering when i take PostHeader out of the FlatList? Its parent is then still being rerendered but the PostHeader isn't. I think this is expected behaviour to prevent child components from rerenering even when their parent(s) do

Comment: add a `console.log` on render before returning to see which component re-renders. This can help us to understand I think.

Comment: Already did, they all rerender, the parent scene, PostHeader, its children, even one child of PostHeader which also has a return false in shouldUpdate.

Comment: Below the FlatList youll see the PostComment component, which is a sticky bottom TextInput. Every keystroke triggers a rerender in all components

Comment: Maybe you should look into PureComponent

Comment: Also tried that, to no avail. I really think it has to do with the way ListHeaderComponent internally works

Answer (score 3):

Turns out, it wasn't rerendering, it was unmounting en mounting my component due to this:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13602#issuecomment-300608431